# How to have live reload LoopBack Projects?

Tags: node.js, npm, loopbackjs

Is there any way to have `loopback` projects in livereload? to avoid stoping `node .` command and starting again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nodemon` would just do this : restart node when a change in the file system is detected.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. this saved me so much of time. just I had roreload explorer.